# Magento 2 - Product options drop-down empty on front-end

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, dropdown-attribute

We are doing a mass product integration. For configurable products we are getting an issue where options are not appearing within the drop-down like so:

[image: Product - no options]

I've narrowed it down to the following method: `$product->getData("options");` which is returning:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
```

From the admin, everything looks fine:

[image: Configurations are correct within the admin]

Configurations are set-up correctly, 1 has available stock, all are enabled. Am I missing something?